# excel sum till a specific number

Tags: excel, sum

I am a total noob on excel so here i am looking for answers.

Best to explain this on a example.

I have in a row numbers from 1-1000000. I would like to sum them till 1000.

How do you do that?

Comment: Do you mean up to row 1000, or have the sum go no larger than 1000, or only sum the numbers which are no greater than 1000?

Comment: the second one...i dont want that the sum is greater then 1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With values in row #1, in **A2** enter:

=A1

In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A2="","",IF((A2+B1>1000),"",A2+B1))
```

and copy across.  Finally in **A3** enter:

```
=LOOKUP(88^99,2:2)
```

For example:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To avoid the *"Helper"* column, I would use the following *UDF:*

```
Public Function SumUntil(rIn As Range, Limit As Double) As Double
    Dim r As Range, t As Double
    SumUntil = 0
    For Each r In rIn
        t = SumUntil
        SumUntil = SumUntil + r.Value
        If SumUntil > Limit Then
            SumUntil = t
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

**=SumUntil(1:1,1000)**

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#2:**

To **count** the number of values that were summed, I would use a different *UDF*:

```
Public Function CountUntil(rIn As Range, Limit As Double) As Long
    Dim r As Range, t As Double, i As Long
    Dim SumUntil As Double
    SumUntil = 0
    i = 0
    For Each r In rIn
        i = i + 1
        t = SumUntil
        SumUntil = SumUntil + r.Value
        If SumUntil > Limit Then
            CountUntil = i - 1
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

Comment: this works, but i have about 10 rows of numbers and i dont want to add another 20 rows. Is their any other way?

Comment: thank you very much. Just 1 more question. How do you count all the numbers you have sum together?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
  =if(sum(A1:A1000000)>1000,1000,sum(A1:A1000000))
```

Comment: this isnt working, because i only get the value 1000. I want that it sums up till 1000, but it can also be less.

Lets say i want to get to value=9
1+2+3=6...i want that it say 6 and not 9

Comment: You are not making any sense- the formula works-  it's adds up a range to a max of 1000, if the value of the range is less it will show less.  You need to explain your problem much better

Comment: U were asked was it row 1000 or value 1000 and u said value -  now you mean row???

Comment: It actually does provide an answer to the question